# Getting error on loading image from https url using Picasso library

Tags: android, picasso

In my application I'm trying to load image from an https URL using Picasso library.I am unable to load image into ImageView. I am using Picasso 2.5.2 and I am setting the image as follows:

```
  Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(GlobalVariable.movieDetails.get(0).getVideo_cover_image())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.animation_placeholder)
            .error(R.drawable.animation_placeholder)
            .into(iv_image);
```

Comment: have you checked your URL in a browser?

Comment: @RahulChandrabhan yes its showing in the browser.

Comment: post log. You can attach a listener to Picasso too. Provide Image link if possible.

Comment: @rupinderjeet it  shows the drawable image at error. the url for the image :- https://192.168.0.149:9999/ucine/uploads/moviecoverimage/thumb/movie_image2018-01-31-07-12-08.jpg

Comment: wow, that's a local link, I can't access it. In LogCat, check warning messages when you start to load the image, Picasso will output some warning if it can't load the image.

Comment: its a local image, you should check logcat, picasso has shown some error in that.

Comment: Your image needs to be hosted publicly for it to be accessed over the internet

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl) && !isValidUrl(imageUrl)) {
                iv_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.default);

            } else {
                Picasso.with(context)
                        .load(imageUrl)
                        .resize(70, 70)//if you want resize image
                        .centerInside()
                        .into(iv_image, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess() {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError() {
                                iv_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.default);
                            }
                        });
            }
```

**validate URL**

```
 public static boolean isValidUrl(String string) {

    boolean b = Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(string).matches();
    return b;
}
```

Comment: https://192.168.0.149:9999/ucine/uploads/moviecoverimage/thumb/movie_image2018-01-31-07-12-08.jpg

this image is local url so run app on local network

Comment: yes this is local url  and i run on local server as well ,when using Glide it work fine but by using picasso it  does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Picasso provide a listener for image loading.

Use below code and check image loading status either Success or Error.

```
 Picasso.with(mContext)
        .load(GlobalVariable.movieDetails.get(0).getVideo_cover_image())
        .placeholder(R.drawable.animation_placeholder)
        .error(R.drawable.animation_placeholder)
        .into(iv_imagenew, 
                    new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                          //Image Loaded
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                         //Error while Loading
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

please use resize(horizontalSize, verticalSize) method of picaso to resize image. may be your image size is to large thats why it will not load so , please try resize(horizontalSize, verticalSize)

```
Picasso.with(context)
       .load(GlobalVariable.movieDetails.get(0).getVideo_cover_image())
       .placeholder(R.drawable.animation_placeholder)
       .error(R.drawable.animation_placeholder)
       .into(iv_image);
       .resize(600, 200) // resizes the image to these dimensions (in pixel). does not respect aspect ratio
       .into(imageViewResize);
```

Comment: can you give me your image URL?